# ListView recycling switches seekbar position

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, seekbar

I have a strange problem.
I have a custom `ListView` with `BaseAdapter`. In my `ListView` row layout, I have few `TextView`s, `Buttons`, and a `SeekBar`. Everything works great, no problems with anything except with recycling.

What happens:
All `SeekBar`'s are hidden, except one which is visible. The `SeekBar` is visible when `MediaPlayer` on row is playing. That part is working great too.

But, when user scrolls up or down, and the row with visible `SeekBar` is out of view, it recycles, and `SeekBar` is recycled too and it keeps updating even tho it's not visible and that row is not playing(mp). And when users scrolls back to return to the view which is playing, `SeekBar` is visible, but not updating and it's position is 0. Instead random `SeekBar` is being updated, but it's not visible(I did test when all `SeekBar`'s are visible so I know that happens)

Of course I could've done most idiotic solution and disable ListView recycling but this makes user experience really bad and could possibly make app run out of memory, and using `LargeHeap` is lame. 
So the following methods are out of question.

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return getCount();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

My question: Is there any obvious solution to this?
How do I keep only one row from being recycled?
I won't post code until it's really necessary, the code is too large. Instead I will just post important parts related to the issue:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    holder = null;
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        holder = new Ids(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (Ids) row.getTag();
    }

    rowItemClass = (ListViewRow) getItem(position);
    if (Globals.isPlaying && Globals.pos == position) {        
        holder.seekbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.seekbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);    
    }

    holder.seekbar.setTag(position);
    final Ids finalHolder = holder;

    ...
    OnClickListener{....
    Globals.mp.start();
    finalHolder.seekbar.setProgress(0);
    finalHolder.seekbar.setMax(Globals.mp.getDuration());
    ..

    updateTimeProgressBar = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (Globals.isPlaying) {  
                finalHolder.seekbar.setProgress(Globals.mp.getCurrentPosition());
                int currentPosition = Globals.mp.getCurrentPosition();
                handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
            }
        }
    };

    handler.postDelayed(updateTimeProgressBar, 100);
    finalHolder.seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            handler.removeCallbacks(updateTimeProgressBar);
            Globals.mp.seekTo(finalHolder.seekbar.getProgress());
            int currentPosition = Globals.mp.getCurrentPosition();
            handler.postDelayed(updateTimeProgressBar, 500);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            handler.removeCallbacks(updateTimeProgressBar);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        // Intentionally left empty
        }
    });
}
```

and That's it.
Why is this happening?
Is there a way to disable recycling for one row?
Would be it be a bad idea to update all `SeekBar`s in `ListView` since only 1 mp will be playing? How bad is that for performance?

Comment: What about keeping a reference about it's state, and checking whether the row is visible again. When it's visible you can reassign the state which is constantly updated while the view itself is recycled.

Comment: you can do it by notifItemChanged(position).

Comment: How do I keep reference about row state?

I did try checking `if (holder.seekbar.getVisiblity==View.VISIBLE)` but this didn't work at all for some reason. Not sure if it was reading wrong `Seekbar`. 

What about `notifyItemChanged` method? Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll outline one of the best ways to tackle this (in my opinion, of course) while respecting a `ListView's` ability to recycle.

But first, this has *got to go*:

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return getCount();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

**Solution:**

Subclass `SeekBar` and let it handle all updates:

- Define two methods that will mark **this** `SeekBar` *active* & *inactive*.
- When marking a `SeekBar` *active*, provide the current position (progress). Alongside, *post* the `Runnable` that will update this `SeekBar`
- When marking a `SeekBar` *inactive*, simply remove callbacks for the `Runnable` and call it a day

Inside your `Adapter`, the only state that you need to maintain is keeping track of the currently playing song. You can do this either by tracking the *position* as seen by your `ListView`, or by holding on to the `ID` of the currently playing track (this, of course, will only work if your model uses IDs).

Something like this:

```
// Define `setActiveAtPosition(int position)` and `setInactive()` 
// in your custom SeekBar

if (Globals.isPlaying && Globals.pos == position) {   
    // Define `setActiveAtPosition(int position)` in your custom SeekBar     
    holder.seekbar.setActiveAtPosition(Globals.mp.getCurrentPosition());
    holder.seekbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    holder.seekbar.setInactiveForNow();
    holder.seekbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);    
}
```

**Requested code:**

Custom Seekbar class implementation:

```
public class SelfUpdatingSeekbar extends SeekBar implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    private boolean mActive = false;

    private Runnable mUpdateTimeProgressBar = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (Globals.isPlaying) {
                setProgress(Globals.mp.getCurrentPosition());
                postDelayed(this, 100L);
            }
        }
    };

    public SelfUpdatingSeekbar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void setActive() {
        if (!mActive) {
            mActive = true;
            removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeProgressBar);
            setProgress(Globals.mp.getCurrentPosition());
            setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            postDelayed(mUpdateTimeProgressBar, 100L);
        }
    }

    public void setInactive() {
        if (mActive) {
            mActive = false;
            removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeProgressBar);
            setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeProgressBar);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeProgressBar);
        Globals.mp.seekTo(getProgress());
        postDelayed(mUpdateTimeProgressBar, 500);
    }
}
```

In your adapter's `getView(...)`:

```
if (Globals.isPlaying && Globals.pos == position) {        
    holder.seekbar.setActive();
} else {
    holder.seekbar.setInactive();    
}
```

Needless to say that you will need to use this custom implementation in your xml layout:

```
<com.your.package.SelfUpdatingSeekbar
    ....
    .... />
```

Comment: Worth to try, gonna try it and see what happens, but it might be a great solution.

Comment: I can't get it to work, I thought that I know how to do this but It turns out I don't. Can you perhaps post code if it's not too much to ask?

Comment: @SlimC. Hi, I've added the implementation. It should work right out of the box. In case I missed something, leave me a comment.

Comment: Amazing! It works like a Swiss watch.  :) Thanks! Amazing answer! I had it all wrong. Again, thank you very much!

Comment: @SlimC.Glad it worked! I have one suggestion (or correction) to make. Instead of the suggested method names - `setActive() & setInactive()`, use something more descriptive - for instance - `setPlayerActive() & setPlayerInactive()`. The reason I say this - `setActive()` is a very generic method name (in the same vein as `setVisible()` or `setEnabled()`) and may become part of the official API of class `View`(or one of its subclasses). To avoid problems later, use a more descriptive method name. I might be over-thinking this, but its better to be safe than sorry :).

Comment: That is a very wise idea, there is no such thing as over-thinking in coding in my opinion. :D Although I already did that, after `SeekBar` was fixed, `TextView` started changing position so I had to extend `TextView` too. So I would have two methods with same names, and thats just confusing. :D Starting to think that my code is not so good :D