# Multiple SeekBars associated with MediaPlayer in ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` which displays voice messages (just like WhatsApp's), I'm using `BaseAdapter`, and my layout contains a play `button` and a `SeekBar`.
What I want is to play the audio on the click of the play `button`, and update the `SeekBar`.

So I implemented this custom `SeekBar` which updates itself.

`SelfUpdatingSeekBar.java`:

```
public class SelfUpdatingSeekBar extends SeekBar {

MediaPlayer mp;
boolean mActive;


public void setMediaPlayer(MediaPlayer mp){
    this.mp = mp;
}


Runnable mUpdate = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        long totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
        long currentDuration = mp.getCurrentPosition();

        // Updating progress bar
        int progress = (int)(getProgressPercentage(currentDuration, totalDuration));
        setProgress(progress);
        postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
} ;

public void setActive(int progress) {
    if (!mActive) {
        mActive = true;
        removeCallbacks(mUpdate);
        setProgress(progress);
        post(mUpdate);
    }
}

public void setInactive(int progress) {
    if (mActive) {
        mActive = false;
        removeCallbacks(mUpdate);
    }
    setProgress(progress);
}



public SelfUpdatingSeekBar(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public SelfUpdatingSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public SelfUpdatingSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

public SelfUpdatingSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}



public int getProgressPercentage(long currentDuration, long totalDuration){
    Double percentage = (double) 0;

    long currentSeconds = (int) (currentDuration / 1000);
    long totalSeconds = (int) (totalDuration / 1000);

    // calculating percentage
    percentage =(((double)currentSeconds)/totalSeconds)*100;

    // return percentage
    return percentage.intValue();
}

}
```

This is how my `getView()` looks like:

```
public View getView(final int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup){

    final ViewHolder viewHolder;



    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((MainActivity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sent_voice_bubble, viewGroup, false);

        viewHolder.sent_voice_seekbar = (SelfUpdatingSeekBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sent_seekbar);
        viewHolder.sent_voice_seekbar.setMediaPlayer(mMediaPlayer);
        viewHolder.sent_voice_play = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sent_playAudio);
        viewHolder.sent_voice_container = convertView.findViewById(R.id.sent_vmessagesection);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(((int)(x * 0.7f)), RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        viewHolder.sent_voice_container.setLayoutParams(params);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


            viewHolder.sent_voice_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                // Check if the Item is currently playing 
                    if(list.get(i).isPlaying()){
                        // Stop audio and save  progress
                        stopItemAudio(list.get(i), viewHolder.sent_voice_seekbar);
                        // Change button's image to Pause ||
                        ((ImageView) v).setImageDrawable(((MainActivity) context).pauseDrawable);

                    }else{
                        // Start audio and update the SeekBar
                        playItemAudio(list.get(i), viewHolder.sent_voice_seekbar);
                        // Change button's image to Play >
                        ((ImageView) v).setImageDrawable(((MainActivity) context).playDrawable);
                    }
                }
            });

            if(list.get(i).isPlaying()){
                viewHolder.sent_voice_seekbar.setActive(list.get(i).seekbar_resume_position);
                viewHolder.sent_voice_play.setImageDrawable(((MainActivity) context).pauseDrawable);
            }else{
                viewHolder.sent_voice_seekbar.setInactive(list.get(i).seekbar_resume_position);
                viewHolder.sent_voice_play.setImageDrawable(((MainActivity) context).playDrawable);
            }


    return convertView;
}




public void stopItemAudio(AudioRow item, SelfUpdatingSeekBar seekBar){

    if(mMediaPlayer == null){
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    }

    mMediaPlayer.stop();
    item.setPlaying(false);
    int percentage = getProgressPercentage(mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition(), mMediaPlayer.getDuration());

    item.setSeekBarResumePosition(percentage);
    item.setMediaPlayerResumePosition(mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
    seekBar.setInactive(percentage);
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}
public void playItemAudio(final AudioRow item, SelfUpdatingSeekBar seekBar){
    if(mMediaPlayer == null){
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    }

    try {
        mMediaPlayer.reset();
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(item.audioPath);
        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        mMediaPlayer.seekTo(item.mediaPlayer_resume_position);
        seekBar.setActive(item.seekbar_resume_position); // Starts from where it stopped
        mMediaPlayer.start();

        // declaring Item started to play
        item.setPlaying(true);
        notifyDataSetChanged();

        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                item.setSeekBarResumePosition(0);
                item.setPlaying(false);
            }
        });
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



public int getProgressPercentage(long currentDuration, long totalDuration){
    Double percentage = (double) 0;

    long currentSeconds = (int) (currentDuration / 1000);
    long totalSeconds = (int) (totalDuration / 1000);

    // calculating percentage
    percentage =(((double)currentSeconds)/totalSeconds)*100;

    // return percentage
    return percentage.intValue();
}

}
```

The problem is when I click on `Item1`, and it starts playing, and click on `Item2` both SeekBars animate at the same time, and that is expected since I did not stop `Item1` on the click of `Item2`

My question is:

- What is the proper way to stop the previous played `Item1` on the click of `Item2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SeekBar` implementation should not have its own `MediaPlayer`. Have only one `MediaPlayer` instance in your activity. Every time a "play" button is clicked in your list view you do something like this:

```
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = ((MainActivity) context).getSingleMediaPlayer();
((MainActivity) context).setCurrentlyPlayingItem(i);
mMediaPlayer.reset();
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(item.audioPath);
mMediaPlayer.prepare();
notifyDatasetHasChanged()
```

Now on your `getView()` implementation, if the first argument: `i` is not equal to the currently playing item of `MainActivity` its `SeekBar` should be at zero.

`MainActivity` should also be the one implementing the update runnable. At this point you might want to use just a normal `SeekBar`. To update the correct View, you need to figure out first if it is visible, because the user could have scrolled to a different position, so you need this function in your `MainActivity`:

```
public View getVisibleItemView(int position){
        if(listview.getCount() > 0) {
            int start = listview.getFirstVisiblePosition();
            for (int i = start, j = listview.getLastVisiblePosition(); i <= j; i++) {
                if (i == position) {
                    return listview.getChildAt(i - start);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This function returns the view with the `SeekBar` that you want to update, but only if it is visible, otherwise it returns null. in your update runnable you should call it, and if the result is not null, you update the `SeekBar`.

Also, you might want to consider using an interface instead of casting context references to `MainActivity` in your adapter.

Comment: Thank you ! About the update runnable being in the MainActivity it was meant to be like that, but I saw this answer here, and I thought it's more reliable  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33807340/listview-recycling-switches-seekbar-position

Comment: The problem with that approach is that when you want to play a new audio you need to figure out which `SeekBar` was playing before so that you can stop its updates. That answer uses global static variables to solve that problem. Having a single `Runnable` and a single `MediaPlayer` in the activity is another solution. I believe its better because aditionally, you can stop or resume updates and playback easily on activity lifecycle callbacks like `onStop()` and `onStart()`